# How to get value text in listbox delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have code like this, I try in Delphi XE :

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  li : TListBoxItem;
  tt : TText;
begin
  ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
  for I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    li := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
    li.Parent := ListBox1;
    tt := TText.Create(li);
    tt.Parent := li;
    tt.Text := IntToStr(i);
    tt.Name := 'text' + IntToStr(i);
    li.ItemData.Detail := 'Lis' + IntToStr(i);
    ListBox1.AddObject(li);
  end;
  ListBox1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

How to get value text in listboxitem delphi?

I try this code but cannot :

```
for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
begin
    h := TText(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i].ToString);
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to read the Text property?

Comment: I want read text of ttext

Comment: So why not do that? (ListBox1.Items.Objects[i] as TText).Text

Comment: (ListBox1.Items.Objects[i] as TText).Text is error access violent.

Comment: I have found the solution, this correct code:

Comment: Listbox1.listitem[i].findcomponent(name ttext)

thanks your reply David

Comment: FindComponent is surely not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
//you should try this
for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
begin
    h := TText(ListBox1.Items.ListItems[i]);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items.ListItems[i].Text);
end;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.